# How to scale horizontally a Parse Server?

Tags: azure, mongodb, scaling, parse-server

My current setup is:

1 Parse Server - 2.6.3

1 MongoDB Server - 3.4.9

Both running on Ubuntu VMs.

In a few weeks, we are expecting our user base to grow significantly! We are currently using 2 VMs on Azure... 1 as a Parse Server and the other as a MongoDB Server.

Could someone guide me through the steps to add 1 VM, for each of the above types? (+1 Parse Server and +1 MongoDB Server (it's something I've never done before!))

I believe I'm going to need a load balancer... am I right? How would it play along with the Parse Server?

Answer (score 1):

**Availability Set**

First, you need to understand the concept of Availability Sets, this is a pre-requisite for High Availability:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/manage-availability

Ideally, you have one for your Web Servers and another for the Database (not the same one for both!).

A VM can only be placed in an Availability Set during its creation, that said, if you don't have one configured on your VMs at the moment, you will need to redeploy. No worries, its easy! Here's the process:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/change-availability-set

**Load Balancer**

Now that you have the AS configured, you can deploy and configure the Load Balancer.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-ilb-arm-portal

For the Web Servers, you may want to configure External Load Balancers instead. Make sure to also look at the Application Gateway capabilities.

**MongoDB**

Bear in mind that to achieve High Availability with MongoDB, you need at least 3 nodes and there's some additional configuration you have to perform to be able to failover the servers.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/replica-set-deployment/

**Parse Server**

As far I know there are no special requirements to be able to scale the Parse Server, but you can also use the process described in this article:

http://blog.kontena.io/how-to-install-and-run-private-parse-server-in-production/